# Работа с данными при включенном выводе ошибок

Tags: php, laravel, warning

Делаю проект на laravel. Идеология такая, что даже предупреждений быть не должно.

Столкнулся вот с чем, надо перебрать массив и записать в отдельный сумму элементов.

Массив для перебора:

```
array(
 [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#631 (7) {
    ["value"]=> 153,
    ["name"]=> "elem1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#632 (7) {
    ["value"]=> 1700,
    ["name"]=> "elem2"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#633 (7) {
    ["value"]=> 100,
    ["name"]=> "elem1"
  }
)
```

Пишу такой код:

```
foreach($results as $res){
    $naw_arr[$res->name] += $res->value;
}
```

Получаю:

```
Undefined index: elem1
```

Делать проверки внутри цикла, мне кажется, слишком затрудняющий понимание способ, особенно если учесть масштаб проекта.

Есть способ проще?
Или вообще отключить вывод ошибок и всё будет работать в таком виде?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($results as $res){
    $naw_arr[$res->name] += $res->value;
}
```

Когда первый раз происходит итерация, то получается сложение с еще не существующим элементом, отсюда и ошибка.

Как один из вариантов, достаточно сделать так:

```
$naw_arr = array();
foreach($results as $res){
    if (!isset($naw_arr[$res->name])) $naw_arr[$res->name] = 0;
    $naw_arr[$res->name] += $res->value;
}
```

P.S. Вывод ошибок в любом случае на продакшине должен быть отключен, в режиме разработки их надо видеть если они есть и исправлять.

Comment: в этом и дело, что в каждом месте писать isset`ы я не вижу целевой пользы, однако видел много мнений что это нужно/полезно. действительно ли это так нужно? отказавшись от этого можно сильно уменьшить количество кода повысив эффективность поддержки продукта и повысить скорость разработки. тем более что на продакшене вывод ошибок должен быть отключен

Comment: @Maximmka убрать isset'ы - называется экономия на копейках, вы больше навредите эффективности работы в других местах, поверьте) Получать варнинги куда более ресурсоемкое дело. Вам в любом случае надо задать первое слагаемое для сложения. Можно вложить эти 2 строчки в одну, но по эффективности это будет тоже самое что я Вам предложил в ответе. Вы должны понимать что система должна понимать с чем она работает и что за переменные перед ней, проверки всегда нужны не скупитесь на проверки.

Comment: @Maximmka Кстати на сколько мне известно, Laravel конечно крутой фрейм, НО его результаты производительности уступают почти всем существующим и актуальным фреймам (5.4 так точно), если Вы так сильно экономите, что не хотите даже добавить ISSET, удивительно почему ваш выбор пал именно на данный фрейм))).